# Webpack build and deploy process

Tags: gulp, webpack

I have just started using Webpack via a recommendation and am looking for some guidance on how it should be implemented for build and deploy purposes.

I currently have it up and running nicely using webpack-dev-server and some Gulp tasks.

Traditionally I would use Gulp or Grunt to concat files among other things and then use the task runner to copy all my files and assets to a dist or build directory from where I would deploy everything.

At the minute, Webpack does it's thing and builds the bundle file, images etc and then copies them to the build dir, using the [hash].js naming convention.

So my question is, what is the standard practice for then copying over my index.html file and then correctly linking it to the js file to be used in production.

Unless I am completely misunderstanding how Webpack should be used, should there not be some way for me to do this, with the ultimate outcome being me having the ability to navigate to the build dir and see my app up and running as it should be?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using a plugin to move my index.html. Make sure your webpack.output.publicPath points to your site so it can link images and other resources.

```
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

var webpack_config = {

    //Other configs here

    output: {
        publicPath: 'http://localhost/'
    },

   //Other configs here

    plugins:[
         new CopyWebpackPlugin([
                {from: './index.html', to: './index.html'},
            ], {
                ignore: [
                    '*.txt',
                    {glob: '**/*', dot: true}
                ]
            })
    ],

    //Other configs here

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have gone with the option of setting up Gulp tasks to handle all of this now.